# Using CHECK constraints for unique characters and from other columns PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have a designed table called STAFF with 3 columns for use in PostgreSQL.

```
staffId VARCHAR(6) PK,
firstName VARCHAR(50),
lastName VARCHAR(50)
```

I would like to build a CHECK constraint so that the first 2 letters of staffId must match the first letter of firstName and the first letter of lastName, and that the last four numbers cannot be the same as another entry in staffId.

E.g.

```
John Smith - JS0001,
Lisa Jones - LJ0002
```

so if Joanne Smith were to join the team then JS0002 would fail due to Lisa Jones already having 0002.

How can I do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing that prefix to begin with. If it's always the same, just create a view that concatenates that information

Comment: Is what I'm looking to achieve something that wouldn't normally be done?

Comment: One rule of good database design is to not store information that can (easily) be derived from existing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem like good database design.  You should simply declare `StaffId` as a `serial` column and let it be an integer.  Voila!  That's done.

Integers are generally more efficient than strings for foreign key references.  They also uniquely identify staff, even when their name changes.

For instance, in the country where I live women (often) and men (sometimes) change their names when they get married or divorced.  That would totally throw off your scheme.

All that said, you can do what you want with `unique` and `check` constraints:

```
alter table staff add constraint chk_staffId
    check (substr(staffId, 1, 1) = substr(firstname, 1, 1) and
           substr(staffId, 2, 1) = substr(lastname, 1, 1) and
           staffId ~ '^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{4}$'
          );
```

Then the constraint would be implemented as an index on an expression:

```
create index unq_staffId_number on (substr(staffid, 3, 4));
```